# Error when exporting data from SQL server database

Tags: sql-server

I try to export data-only from SQL server using `task->generate scripts` menu and get this following error. what does it mean? I'm not so familiar with this SQL server, so this bunch of text really confusing for me.

```
Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlScriptPublish.SqlScriptPublishException: An error occurred while scripting the objects. ---> Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SmoException: Cyclic dependencies found. at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SmoDependencyOrderer.DependencyGraphTraversal(Int32 num, Dictionary`2 dictionary, List`1 sortedList, HashSet`1 visited, HashSet`1 current) at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SmoDependencyOrderer.DependencyGraphTraversal(Int32 num, Dictionary`2 dictionary, List`1 sortedList, HashSet`1 visited, HashSet`1 current) at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SmoDependencyOrderer.DependencyGraphTraversal(Int32 num, Dictionary`2 dictionary, List`1 sortedList, HashSet`1 visited, HashSet`1 current) at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SmoDependencyOrderer.SortDictionary(Dictionary`2 dictionary) at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SmoDependencyOrderer.SortDataSet(DataSet ds) at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SmoDependencyOrderer.SortDataSet(List`1 objectList, Dictionary`2 idDictionary, DataSet ds) at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SmoDependencyOrderer.ExecuteQueryUsingTempTable(List`1 objectList, List`1 list, String query) at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SmoDependencyOrderer.ResolveTableOnlyDependencies() at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SmoDependencyOrderer.ResolveDependencies() at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SmoDependencyOrderer.Order(IEnumerable`1 urns) at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ScriptMaker.DiscoverOrderScript(IEnumerable`1 urns) at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ScriptMaker.ScriptWorker(List`1 urns, ISmoScriptWriter writer) at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ScriptMaker.Script(Urn[] urns, ISmoScriptWriter writer) at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlScriptPublish.SqlScriptGenerator.DoScript(ScriptOutputOptions outputOptions) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlScriptPublish.GeneratePublishPage.worker_DoWork(Object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) at System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.OnDoWork(DoWorkEventArgs e) at System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.WorkerThreadStart(Object argument)
```

Comment: The error mentions cyclic dependencies. Can you share more info on your database structure/tables?

Comment: which version of SQL Server and Management Console are you using?

Comment: You have a cycle in your data structure. To find out what provokes this error a demo of your data structure would be beneficial.

Comment: @kiks73 i'm using SQL server 2008 and Management Studio 12.0.2000.8

Comment: @shree.part18 I'm afraid I can't because of my office policies. So, this is all about cyclic dependencies? I will try to figure it out. Be right back.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to install Sql Server Management 2008 R2 to connect to your SQL Server 2008 instance.
In my case this solved the problem and I generated the script in this way.

Comment: it still giving similar error: 
Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlScriptingEngine.CyclicalForeignKeyException: The selected database contains foreign keys that create a cycle. Publishing data only is not supported for databases with cyclical foreign key relationships. at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlScriptPublish.GeneratePublishPage.worker_DoWork(Object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) at System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.OnDoWork(DoWorkEventArgs e) at System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.WorkerThreadStart(Object argument)